# Cloudrun is charged for idle time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, billing

**The issue:**
Cloud run services are supposed to be charged only for the time spent on processing the request.
We have deployed the python service and enabled authentication. According to google docs (https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing) only authenticated requests from services are billed. Non-authenticated requests (from bots, scanners, etc.) are getting 403.
The logs are showing that requests are going to cloudrun service during working hours (8:00-16:00 UTC window) (though not frequently, 4-5 times a day). The requests are coming from our internal services to auto-generated cloudrun url, trigger some data to be generated and sent back to the service.
We are paying ~100$/month per each cloud run service and would like to decrease the costs.

**Expected behaviour:**
Request comes to the service. The container is spun. Request is processed and we are billed only for the time that container exists. Then container is shut down and "Billable container instance time" metric drops to 0.

**Real behaviour:**
The metrics are showing straight line in "Billable container instance time" which means that container is never stopped being billed.

Please, assist on the matter.

**UPD:** The solution was to decrease minimum instances to 0. Previously it was set to min=1, max=4 so 1 instance was always running as idle.

Comment: You have parameters that keep the instance up and running outside the request processing time. Are you using min-instance or no-CPU throttled options? In addition, how many CPUs/memory do you have on your services, and how long take the request processing?

Comment: Hey @guillaumeblaquiere, found a solution and wrote in the issue.

Comment: I see thee following note at the end of the pricing page: "2 idle min instance refers to idle billable time for instances kept warm using minimum instances. Idle instances that are not minimum instances are not charged". Are you i such case?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#billable-time